# quicksort algorithm not sorting final element?

Tags: c#, quicksort

I have this code that I wrote using an algorithm I found on Wikipedia:

```
    public static void quicksort(int[] arr, int low, int hi)
    {
        if(low < hi)
        {
            int pivot = part( arr, low, hi);
            quicksort( arr, low, pivot - 1);
            quicksort( arr, pivot + 1, hi);
        }
    }
    public static int part(int[] arr, int low, int hi)
    {
        int pivot = arr[hi];

        int i = low;
        for(int j = low; j < hi - 1; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                swap(arr, i, j);
                i++;
            }
        }
        swap(arr, i, hi);
        return i;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] ar, int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = ar[a];
        ar[a] = ar[b];
        ar[b] = temp;
    }
```

Given this input:

```
31, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4
```

one should expect to get:

```
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 31
```

but instead I get:

```
4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 31, 5
```

What gives?

I call the initial sort with: `quicksort(array, 0, array.Length - 1);`

Comment: Consider trying `quicksort( array, 0, array.Length )`

Comment: Goes out of bounds on the array when I do that. Zero-indexing means that the upper index is one less than the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call it using `Length - 1`, then this loop:

```
 for (int j = low; j < hi - 1; j++)
```

..should be:

```
 for (int j = low; j <= hi ; j++)
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. I just needed a second set of eyes to look at it because I couldn't see that error. I'll accept ASAP but it won't let me right now.

Comment: I think you still need the -1, i.e j <= hi - 1.